# NSManagedObjectContext performBlock thread

Tags: core-data

I am confused with the documentation expain about the performBlock: and PerformBlockAndWait:
It says: performBlock is async and withWait:is sync in the receiver's queue.
Is that "receiver" refers to the NSManagedObjectContext?
If the context is private type so the block executes in the background thread, if the context is main type and the block executes in the main thread?
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. You understood the documentation correctly.

"Receiver" refers to the existing context, so if this is a background context, the block will be executed in a background thread, if it is a main context, on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will perform the block on the context's queue (on a background thread, in the case of a private queue context). However, the `performBlockAndWait:` method will ALSO block the calling thread until the block has finished executing on the background thread.

Comment: So it seems like, performBlock likes to dispatch_asyn, and performBlockAndWait likes to dispatch_syn, and the queue depends on private type(background queue), main type context(main thread queue)? thanks